# Using Columns in a RegExp in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I'm using the following query with `regexp`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.company, a.name, b.title, b.description, b.t_id
FROM a, b
WHERE ( b.title
REGEXP "[[:<:]]a.company[[:>:]]" OR b.description
REGEXP "[[:<:]]a.company[[:>:]]" OR b.title
REGEXP "[[:<:]]a.name[[:>:]]"  OR b.description
REGEXP "[[:<:]]a.name[[:>:]]" ) AND a.company !=  '' AND a.name !=  ''
```

But, this query is not giving any result nor its giving any syntax error.

When I replace `a.company` or `a.name` with any of the company name then this query runs fine. Why doesn't this query work with the column names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're searching for the literal string `a.company`, and not the column. Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.company, a.name, b.title, b.description, b.t_id
FROM a, b
WHERE 
    ( 
        b.title REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]', a.company, '[[:>:]]') 
        OR b.description REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]', a.company, '[[:>:]]') 
        OR b.title REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]', a.name, '[[:>:]]')
        OR b.description REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]', a.name, '[[:>:]]')
    ) 
    AND a.company !=  '' AND a.name !=  ''
```

This provides the `regexp` with the value of the column, not the string `'a.company'`. Since my guess is that you want to compare the column value (and not the column name), you will need to concatenate your `regexp` together.

You can test this with this query:

```
select
    'My col: a.company' as Test1,
    'My col: ' + a.company as Test2
from
    a
```

Here, `Test1` will always be the value `My col: a.company`, while Test2 will be `My col: <company col value here>`.

Comment: You're using MS SQL Server string concatenation syntax, which MySQL doesn't support.  Use this syntax instead: `CONCAT('[[:<:]]', a.company, '[[:>:]]')`

Comment: Thanks Eric and thanks Bill ! well honestly im learning a lot with the help of you all. Thanks again to stackoverflow and all its members :-)