# MySQL Regexp to match domain with or without subdomain

Tags: php, mysql

I have:

- A `string` with value `www.facebook.com`
- A column `allowed_domain` with value `facebook.com`

I try to see if the domain string (with subdomains) matches the column (without subdomain) as such:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
   WHERE 'www.facebook.com' REGEXP '^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*' + allowed_domain + '$'
```

The string "www.facebook.com" is extracted from the `referrer` in my actual code.

[You can see the regexp I'm using in action here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%5C.%29%2afacebook.com%24&input=facebook.com%0Awww.facebook.com%0Aapps.facebook.com%0Awww.apps2.www.facebook.com%0Awww.notfacebook.com%0Anotfacebook.com%0Aapps.facebook.com.notfacebook.com)

My problem is that the regexp isn't matching in MySql. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here: [Using Columns in a RegExp in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326063/using-columns-in-a-regexp-in-mysql).  I needed to send a single string object into the regexp as such:

```
REGEXP concat('^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*', domain, '$')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try better a like query:

```
... WHERE domain like '%.facebook.com'
```

You may also add an rule for facebook.com with no sub domain but that should work.

Comment: If I were to use `LIKE` what I need is `WHERE 'www.facebook.com' like '%.' + domain ` which doesn't work in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you found is inaccurate. That regex can match unwanted domains like `fakefacebook.com`. Please try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE allowed_domain='www.facebook.com' OR 'www.facebook.com' LIKE concat('%.', allowed_domain)
```

I'm using this query in my Squid ACL External Helper and it working like a charm.

Comment: It wouldn't match `fakefacebook.com`, but it would match for example `fake.facebook.com`. Which was the intended design.