# How to select from MySQL database rows containing more than 3 required words in the same column?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a large database (over 2 million rows) where I store statistics from users. Users have Unique IDs which contain parts (for example hashed MAC address).
The example Unique ID string is:

"AAAAAA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-FFFFFFF"

Sometimes a part of the Unique ID changes and then it's for example:

"ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX"

I want to identify users and select all rows, where at least 3 (or different value) Unique ID parts match, using PHP. Is there any useful syntax which I could use to do that? I know that I can select all rows containing at least 1 Unique ID part, then explode to an array by the "-" character and check if contains at least 3 same words, but I believe that it isn't the fastest possible way.

Basically, I would like to use something like:

```
WHERE `UniqueID` REGEXP 'AAAAAA|BBBBBB|CCCCCC|DDDDDD|EEEEEE|FFFFFFF';
```

But selecting only if 3 of 6 words match.

Comment: Your unique id should be split into multiple columns, then this would be much simpler.  Also, do the positions of the matches have to match?

Comment: if you have always the same type of data 'credit card style with letters look-alike' you might be interested in [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392197/selecting-part-of-a-field-with-a-regex) or [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326063/using-columns-in-a-regexp-in-mysql) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315647/regex-credit-card-number-tests)

Comment: Thanks for answers! Unfortunately, the columns can contain "unique id parts" not in the same order. Sometimes the Unique ID can be shorter (for example 4 instead of 6 parts), etc. Those parts are usually hashed hardware information (numbers in random length, maximum 12 characters long).

Comment: 'AAAAAA|BBBBBB|CCCCCC|DDDDDD|EEEEEE|FFFFFFF' is equivalent to  like a or like b or like c or like d or like e **or** like f. but you want at least three matches regardless of their position??

Comment: Yes @krishKM, that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOU MIGHT WANT TO CHECK PERFORMANCE**

Consider this query which uses inStr to check if a string is available within your id string. i used substring_index to extract the parts. just in case if you are interested in splitting or extracting part of the id string to create a temporary table but for this answer you can ignore it.

Ideally create your own stored procedure with keyword1, keyword2 & keyword3 as in parameter and then you can perform the search and return results.

Where condition checks whether the keyword1, 2 & 3 are found in your id string.

```
select 
    'ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX' as Id,
    substring_index('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','-', 1) as part1,
    substring_index(substring_index('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','-', 2),'-', -1) as part2,
    substring_index(substring_index('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','-', 3),'-', -1) as part3,
    substring_index(substring_index('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','-', 4),'-', -1) as part4,
    substring_index(substring_index('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','-', 5),'-', -1) as part5,
    substring_index(substring_index('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','-', 6),'-', -1) as part6
from dual
WHERE

    instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','BBBBBB') >= 1 -- keyword1
    and instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','CCCCCC') >= 1 -- keyword2
    and instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX','DDDDDD') >= 1 -- keyword3
;
```

**EDIT**
if the above query is working you can add your logic.

```
select 
    'ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX' as Id


from dual
WHERE
    (
    -- below logic gives true when 3 or more keywords are found. change this accordingly
        (instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX',ik1) >0)+
        (instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX',ik2) >0)+
        (instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX',ik3) >0)+
        (instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX',ik4) >0)+
        (instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX',ik5) >0)+
        (instr('ZZZZZZ-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-DDDDDD-EEEEEE-XXXXXXX',ik6) >0)
    ) >=3

;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tested it and it takes 5 seconds to select from ~2 mln rows database. However, I don't understand one thing: the query should search for 6 keywords, and success only when 3 or more matches. When I add an additional "and instr(`UniqueID`,'xxxxxxxxx') >= 1 -- keyword4" the query doesn't work. So I guess I need to use "OR" but select only if there are 3 matches...

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help. I'll post how I did it using PHP in a separated "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @krishKM I found the best solution for my Unique IDs selection using PHP.

First I made a function which puts Unique ID parts to an array, but keeps "delimeters" on both sides. It helps to prevent incorrect selections, for example when the ID part is very short.

```
function SplitUniqueIDKeepDelimeters($UniqueID, $Delimeter = "-"){
    $UniqueIDParts = array();
    $Remaining = $UniqueID;
    $pos = strpos($Remaining, $Delimeter);
    $firstPart = true;
    while ($pos !== false) {
        $Part = substr($Remaining,0,$pos + 1);
        if(!$firstPart){
            $Part = $Delimeter.$Part;
        }
        $firstPart = false;
        $UniqueIDParts[] = $Part;
        $Remaining = substr($Remaining,$pos+1);
        $pos = strpos($Remaining, $Delimeter);
    }
    if(!$firstPart){
        $Remaining = $Delimeter.$Remaining;
    }
    $UniqueIDParts[] = $Remaining;
    return $UniqueIDParts;
}
```

Then based on @krishKM's answer I created the selection syntax:

```
function GenerateSelectingString($UniqueIDParts, $RowName = "UniqueID", $HowManyMatches = 3){
    $First = true;
    $FinishedString = " (";
    foreach ($UniqueIDParts as $key => $value){
        if(!$First){
            $FinishedString .= "+";
        }
        $First = false;
        $FinishedString .= "(instr(`".$RowName."`,'".$value."') > 0)";

    }
    $FinishedString .= ") >=".$HowManyMatches;
    return $FinishedString;
}
```

Test:

```
$TestArray = SplitUniqueIDKeepDelimeters("21680-7886-2761736077-72316693-753974682-041548389245");
$TestSelectString = GenerateSelectingString($TestArray, "UniqueID");

echo "Unique ID parts array:<br>";
var_dump($TestArray);
echo "<br><br>Query String:<br>";
echo $TestSelectString;
echo "<br>";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `Statistics`.`Statistics` WHERE ".$TestSelectString. " order by `lognumber` DESC;";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($row2);
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "<br>".mysqli_errno($conn) . ": " . mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Unique ID parts array: array(6) { [0]=> string(6) "21680-" [1]=> string(6) "-7886-" [2]=> string(12) "-2761736077-" [3]=> string(10) "-72316693-" [4]=> string(11) "-753974682-" [5]=> string(13) "-041548389245" } 

Query String: ((instr(`UniqueID`,'21680-') > 0)+(instr(`UniqueID`,'-7886-') > 0)+(instr(`UniqueID`,'-2761736077-')
> 0)+(instr(`UniqueID`,'-72316693-') > 0)+(instr(`UniqueID`,'-753974682-') > 0)+(instr(`UniqueID`,'-041548389245') > 0)) >=3

array(60) {  ...
```